# Spring Integration Transaction management using Atomikos

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-transactions, jta, atomikos

I am thinking to create a Spring Integration Spring Boot application to

> ```
> 1-Poll messages from a DB
> 2-Do some processing on it
> 3-Publish messages to EMS Queue
> ```

using Atomikos for Transaction management. My question is: If the above configuration will be transactional with all the required JTA configurations done? Also I have read somewhere, if multiple threads are created in Spring Integration,e.g,using a Splitter, then the context won't to transactional. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you configure the poller as transactional, the flow will run in a transaction, as long as you don't hand off to another thread (via an `ExecutorChannel` or `QueueChannel` channel, for example).

Adding a splitter will not break the transaction boundary as each split will be processed on the same thread.

Comment: If I use inbound channel adapter to poll messages from DB and then pass to splitter, converter, publisher to queue via outbound channel adapter etc , is there any way to cover the whole process in a transaction?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote parser instead of poller (not enough coffee). Yes, configure the poller to be transactional; the transaction will start before the source is polled and commit when the downstream flow completes.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Integration has different requirements for transactions, to Do so you need to pass a transaction manager in the poller metaData, for example:

```
@Bean
    public PollerMetadata pollerMetadata() throws  NamingException   {
        return Pollers.fixedDelay(Long.valueOf(env.getProperty("poller.interval")))
                .transactional(**transactionManager**).get();
    }
```

With

```
 @Autowired
     private PlatformTransactionManager **transactionManager**;
```

And putting :

```
@InboundChannelAdapter(channel = "jpaInputChannel", poller = @Poller(value = "**pollerMetadata**"))
```